# Poedit: Avoid Reordering of translations in .po file

Tags: poedit

I use Poedit in a project for localization. Whenever I change an entry with poedit, it reorders all elements. I think it reorders the elements according to their line number and file but since I´m working with many coders on this project, poedit must not reorder all elements to avoid unneccessary line changes in the repository. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Poedit never, under any circumstances, reorders content of the file when you “change an entry”. Files are *always* saved in the order they had when loaded, and it’s been like this since the very first version.

I have two explanations:

1. Either you’re confusing content of the file with the *view* presented in Poedit (where you can select your preferred *display* order in the View menu), in which case just change the display to whatever you like. But this seems unlikely.
2. Or you’re talking about not “changing an entry” in the file, but *updating the PO file from source code*. If that’s the case, it’s possible that you or some of your coworkers are using some very old version of Poedit. The fix would be to update to the current version, because the *scan* order was fixed to be stable across platforms in v1.6.5 1.3 years ago.

If it’s neither, you [need to describe the issue reproducibly](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot from providing the minimal version to put all the team on. As the 1.6.5 changelog doesn't seem to mention it.

Comment: @tuxayo Are you seriously complaining about a `NEWS` update *over three years old*? It's not reasonable to use any software that old if newer versions exist. Besides, the *detailed* changes log, i.e. `git log`, of course does include this change as well.

Comment: sorry if that sounded like a complain. That was not my intention. (I'm not a native speaker, maybe that's why it didn't sound like a complain to me when proofreading it). It was to say thanks and provide positive feedback. But it sounds like it backfired. :-( I was happy to finally understand why we were having terrible VC conflict issues and the exact version beyond which it's solved. And it's even more great that the info came from the software author himself.

Comment: «It's not reasonable to use any software that old if newer versions exist.»  That's exactly what I'll tell to my colleague still on Ubuntu 14.10 which ships Poedit 1.5.4.